# document.body.style.zoom returning empty string?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

If I set it in the console to a value, it works, and it will also then return that value if I check it. But if I just try to access `document.body.style.zoom`, it returns `""`.

What's with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set a value to the (non-standard) `zoom` css property of the body?  If you didn't, then you shouldn't expect there to be a non-empty value there.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it was nonstandard.